# PAM module configuration, ssh failure in Debian

Tags: ssh, debian, password-policy

**I want to set password policies for users on a Debian VM, like minlen and special char required for the password.**

In my Debian VM I get an error and can´t log in again via SSH to that machine.

**OS Version:** Debian Bullseye 11

**Kernel Version:** Linux 5.10.0-9-amd64 x86_64

**Modifying** the config file /etc/pam.d/common-password starting at the line:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure yescrypt
```

and **inserting** something like shown in (https://www.networkworld.com/article/2726217/how-to-enforce-password-complexity-on-linux.html):

```
minlen=8 dcredit=1 ucredit=1 lcredit=1 ocredit=1
```

*Without any changes at that file I can enter the machine without any problems e.g. Public Key is uploaded correctly, SSH Port is open, SSH and SSHD services are active.*

Again when I try to remote connect via SSH:

```
ssh -v USER@IP
```

**I get in the last lines this error**:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
USER@IP's password:

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Permission denied, please try again.
```